# Is changing the visibility of a virtual method from protected internal to protected a breaking change?

Tags: c#, .net

Is changing a method with `protected internal` visibility to `protected` a breaking change for external callers and implementors of the class?

Also note that the method is virtual so it can be overriden in derived classes.

Before:

```
protected internal virtual string ResolvePropertyName(string propertyName)
{
    return propertyName;
}
```

After:

```
protected virtual string ResolvePropertyName(string propertyName)
{
    return propertyName;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's a breaking change.

Consider code that's in the same assembly, but not in the same class nor in a derived class, and which is calling the `ResolvePropertyName()` method. If you were to change the accessibility from `protected internal` to just `protected`, that code would no longer compile.

There is also the `[InternalsVisibleTo]` to consider. While you can compile the given assembly and detect any *current* usages that would be broken (but not anticipate future possible usages), other assemblies might be granted `internal` access via that attribute, and you can't verify them simply by compiling the current assembly. They would break if you removed the `internal` accessibility modified from such a method, if they are using it.

Comment: I know it is a breaking change for people in the same assembly, by breaking change I meant breaking the external contract of the class. I've updated my question to be more clear.

Comment: I believe my second paragraph addresses that part of your question. The answer is still "yes, it's a breaking change". Of course, if you have not granted `internal` access to other assemblies, then arguably it's not a breaking change. But there's not enough information in your question to know a) what your _actual_ definition of "breaking change" is, and b) what the rest of your assembly looks like (including whether you use `[InternalsVisibleTo]`). (BTW, that the method is `virtual` doesn't seem relevant here).

Comment: meh - A breaking change is always to consumers of your code.

Comment: @YishaiGalatzer: define "consumers". Do you not consider code _within_ the same assembly a "consumer"? Even if that code does in fact _consume_ the code? Even if so, what makes your definition better than someone else's? And in any case, as I have tried to point out multiple times, there may be consumers in _other_ assemblies, depending on information not provided by the OP.

Comment: Obviously you will have to compile the assembly, so other consumers are not broken when you are done. Pretty clear.

InternalsVisibleTo argument has some more merit, but on the same vein you can include consumers using private reflection.

My opinion is not better than yours, it is however very different than yours, mostly because breaking changes is asked in the context of consumers of your project/assembly and mostly the above comments are irrelevant to that case

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends upon who's asking.

1. If you're a developer who works on the code INSIDE the assembly and call `ResolvePropertyName` without deriving from the class that contains `ResolvePropertyName`, then yes. this is a breaking change.
2. If you're working from outside of the assembly, nothing changes, only derived classes can call this method, so you're good.